# Looking for a proverb related to people who don't take a stand

Tags: idiom-requests, proverb-requests

I have come across this very famous proverb many times that blames people who don't take a stand for bad things that happen in the world.

As far as I remember, it had something to do with the world ending and the people who had not taken a stand were to blame. However, I cannot remember the exact wording, nor can I find it anywhere on the internet.

I am open to other suggestions as well...

Comment: Your question is likely off-topic if there is only one such phrase that will satisfy.

Comment: There may be many which satisfy but I am looking for a very specific one. I am not sure if this is the correct forum to ask such a question but I couldn't think of a better place. Please suggest if you have any alternatives.

Comment: If you have indeed heard it many times than you should be able to give us more to go on with. Guessing games i.e. _I am thinking of a word/phrase/etc --what is it?_ do not go over well here.

Comment: There's also Yeats's *The Second Coming*: "Things fall apart; the centre cannot hold ...The best lack all conviction, while the worst Are full of passionate Intensity." https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems/43290/the-second-coming

Comment: @Chappo.. Done. Moreover one of the answers fits my use case so already selected it as correct. Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 6, accepted):

“The only thing necessary for the triumph of evil is for good men to do nothing.” Edmund Burke (in a [letter](http://www.openculture.com/2016/03/edmund-burkeon-in-action.html) addressed to Thomas Mercer).

Comment: This does fit my use case to a certain extent however I am looking for a very specific proverb / quote that's been causing an itch in my brain. Will wait for sometime and, if I don't get the correct answer, will accept yours.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know about a proverb, but just in case we've a problem with naming conventions, you may be thinking of **"First they came ..."** a poem written by the German Lutheran pastor Martin Niemöller (1892–1984). [Further details on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_they_came_...)

> First they came for the socialists, and I did not speak out—
>        Because I was not a socialist.
>   Then they came for the trade unionists, and I did not speak out—
>        Because I was not a trade unionist.
>   Then they came for the Jews, and I did not speak out—
>        Because I was not a Jew.
>   Then they came for me—
> and there was no one left to speak for me.

Answer (score 1):

- > **[Broken reeds](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/reed)**, he proclaimed, damning the people who did not take a stand!.
- > an unreliable or undependable person. (metaphor of a useless,
  >   broken reed in an instrument.) You can't rely on Jim's support.
  >   He's a broken reed. Mr. Smith is a broken reed. His deputy has to make
  >   all the decisions.

This expression refers to Isaiah 36:6, in which the Assyrian general taunts King Hezekiah of Jerusalem about the latter's supposed ally, the Egyptian pharaoh: ‘Lo, thou trusteth in the staff of this broken reed, on Egypt’.